# listening to changes in nested providers

Tags: flutter, provider, mobile-development

I have 2 classes with change notifier, Product which declares each product and ProductProvider which includes a list of products and some methods. I created a GridView of Products using this code.

```
class GridList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context);
    final products = productsData.items;
    return GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        itemCount: products.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 1,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10.0),
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
          return ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (c) => products[i],
            child: ProductItem(),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

in the ProductItem() I have some widgets but most importantly, I have an Icon button that adds the product to Favorite and a button that pushes to the product details screen.

```
  void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
}

IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
                product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border),
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            onPressed: () {
              product.toggleFavoriteStatus();
            },
          ), 

 onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductDetailsScreen.routeName, arguments: product.id);
          },
```

The icon does change fine on the productItem(), I want to have the same behavior in the ProductDetailsScreen, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `ProductDetailsScreen` is a page which displays the whole information of the product tapped, in that case I would recommend passing as an argument the Product Provided and then use `ChangeNotifierProvider.value()` in the `ProductDetailsScreen`

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context, 
  ProductDetailsScreen.routeName,
  arguments: Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false) //I used Products but I don't know the name of your class you used to create the ChangeNotifierProvider
);
```

Then in ProductDetailsScreen just pass the value to `ChangeNotifierProvider.value()` at the beggining and start using it with the consumer

```
ProductDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  final myChangeNotifier;

  ProductDetailsScreen(this.myChangeNotifier);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Product>.value(
      value: myChangeNotifier,
      child: Consumer<Product>(
        build: (context, product, _) => ... //paste the code you uses in ProductDetailsScreen here
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Now when you update the value of products it will update in both pages, so when you return you will see the changes too